# Timestamps on deleted and then undeleted answers

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

When an answer is deleted, then *totally* re-edited before being undeleted, please change the timestamp to reflect the time of the undeletion rather than the time of the original answer.

This sequence of events made one of my Meta answers look incorrect even though it was correct at the moment I posted it.

[This is the edit sequence in question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/171016/revisions). Don't get me wrong - [juergen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172011/juergen-d) did a good job by creating the tag, but by changing and undeleting his answer it [makes mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171019/146015) (10K+ only) look incorrect - which it wasn't at the time I posted it. Note that I'm not concerned about down votes, I'm concerned about context and accuracy.

Comment: What constitutes a total re-edit?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn The undeleted post bears no resemblance to the deleted post. Maybe it should be if any substantial edit takes place then the timestamp is reset - there are already algorithmns in place to determine how substantial an edit is.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the "edited X hours" ago is enough. What you say applies equally well to a post which was just edited substantially, with no deletion magic. If he had just edited and created the tag, your answer would *still* look wrong. The second timestamp takes care of this. The "answered X hours ago" timestamp would be downright confusing if it was reset on deletion.

Stuff changes. The Internet doesn't (or shouldn't) expect you to be up-to-date, no more than you can expect a reporter to fix their published material after getting more information.